# Application for viewing movies, GPS data, and shock-sensor data recorded

Tags: windows, gps, video-player

Looking for an application for viewing movies, GPS data, and shock-sensor data recorded for windows.

Preferably,

- Select individual movie files
- Export all GPS track data to CSV file
- Export all GPS track data to GPX file
- Export all GPS track data to Google Earth KML file
- Export view to PNG image
- Export portion of movie to separate movie file
- Switch dual-channel display modes
- Merge multiple movies into a single large movie
- Arrange ancillary windows to the right of the main window
- Re-center movie(s) in viewer frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dashcam Viewer](https://dashcamviewer.com/) is a software application for viewing movies, GPS data, and shock-sensor data recorded by your dashcam or action cam. Dashcam Viewer supports over 70 camera models. See below for the complete list of supported cameras and features.

Play your dashcam videos on the main screen while watching your vehicle’s speed, distance, position, bearing, and shock-sensor data update on graphs, data displays, and maps. “Geotag” points of interest along your route. Export these to a file. Or import them back in. Export your GPS tracks to common file formats such as comma-separated value (CSV), Google Earth KML, and GPS-exchange (GPX) for further data analysis.